# distinguish between a wireless communication systems engineer and computer networks engineer

Tags: networking

Please I want to know the difference between an MSC in Wireless Communication Systems and  Wireless Computer Networking. Will I learn about computer networks in wireless communication systems? Please I need help on this. I need to choose a masters. Though I have a physics background, I have fallen in love with networking.

Comment: "I have fallen in love with networking" -- get thee to a psychiatrist, it might not be too late for you to escape...

Answer (score 3):

More detail would help.

Lacking any specifics, I guess that studying Wireless Communication Systems would include other radio technologies. I would *hope* that a master's program in either subject would have more to do with the theory and detail of how these systems work. A master's degree in implementing 802.11 networks sounds like a real waste of time & money to me -- that's called vocational training.

Comment: Hear hear. I can't imagine its possible to have an entire masters level course / qualification on wireless computer networking.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really vague question - surely only the institutions you are applying to can tell you want you'll have to study?

Answer (score 0):

I really want the difference between Wireless communications systems engineering and mobile communication systems engineering. What kind of work do the do in the industry and things like that

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment or an edit to your original question - not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not being funny but you really do need to speak to the place offering the masters. What their course offers and what careers it leads on to very much depend on their course content and structure, which will be unique to them. As a broad note, I'd point out there is a lot more to wireless communications than computers communicating wirelessly.